# restrict an array of keyof T within an object literal expression to exactly (keyof T)[]

Tags: typescript

I am trying to restrict the value of an expression within an object literal, like `{x: <(keyof T)[]>[...]}`, to be an array of exactly a subset of `keyof T`, but it appears typescript is, in certain cases, widening the allowed type to just be `string[]`.

Minimal repro:

```
type KEYS = "a" | "b";

const desired_failure : KEYS[] = ["a", "b", "not_ok"]; // typechecker rightly complains
const this_doesnt_fail = {
    foo: <KEYS[]> ["a", "b", "not_ok"], // I would like this to fail,
    bar: <KEYS[]> ["not_ok"], // this *does* fail
}
```

It properly rejects the code within the object literal if the array length is 1, but not when greater than 1.

I have tried a few permutations of `readonly` and `as const` with no success. What am I missing?

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false&target=99&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA0gogTQMpQLxQEQEMNQD6YBGGA3AFBkDGA9gHYDOwUAJhPQJYBOEzA%20gGZZ2AGwCu3KAC5YiJAG0AumihzsGADRENmWtWC9qAawwKSUAPTmooSJQAWESoYicondgHM7wYSCg0AWzBhIQYqOkZrO3Z6XmZqNlp9QRFlAG8yKCyofmpqaQAeeGRFAD4VNU0MYirdfSMTTUsoAEkoAHdqUWFmKGF2ZyiY62ocoWF1TOzCLE5C4vkFctU6g2MFJqtgaPooACp4tj2xkTIAXyA)

typescript 4.0.5

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
type KEYS = "a" | "b";
type Example = {
    foo: KEYS[];
    bar: KEYS[];
}

const desired_failure : KEYS[] = ["a", "b", "not_ok"]; // typechecker rightly complains
const this_doesnt_fail: Example = {
    foo: ["a", "b", "not_ok"], // typechecker rightly complains,
    bar: ["not_ok"], // typechecker rightly complains
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false&target=99&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA0gogTQMpQLxQEQEMNQD6YBGGA3AFCiRRwAeWAtmADbToDeZUXUAZgPZ8AXLERIA2gF1y3KISwAnYfGSTyAXzJkAxnwB2AZ2BQAJhH0BLeRGMB9HlnNMArlahLRktFDHYMAGiJ-TF0+YBs+AGsMKSgAelioSggtAAtkiIh5KHlzAHMU4CYQKB1GJgcDbT1DRJTzfRtjPjNdMPtHYVoGZlYoDhl+IW9fAIxiUZCwyOiA+KgASSgAdz4nJmMoJnMM2vrEvl4HJj9ObjlFYcnwqIlZhOA6-SgAKiazZ8PHMjUgA).

Why?

Because what you are doing is merely "type assertion" (telling the compiler "I know what I'm doing, stop typechecking), instead of actually setting a type (telling the compiler "This value should be this type, please validate").

It is mentioned in the [documentation here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

> A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but it performs no special checking or restructuring of data.

Comment: Interesting. You declared `Example` to be a type. My first idea would be to declare it as an interface. I will go check out the difference. Thanks. :)

Comment: yes this is essentially my current workaround, it's a bit anti-dry though